# Split unlimited length SQL String into two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have seen multiple answers, but none that worked for me.

I send in a string like this `desc1$100$desc2$200` to a stored procedure.

Then I want to to insert it into a temp table like so:

```
|descr|meter|
|desc1|100  |
|desc2|200  |
```

Wanted output ^

```
declare @string varchar(max) 
set @string = 'desc1$100$desc2$200'


declare @table table
        (descr varchar(max),
            meter int
        )

    -- Insert statement
-- INSERT NEEDED HERE


-- Test Select
SELECT * FROM  @table
```

How should I split it?

Comment: You're going to need a string splitter than returns the ordinal position, to start with, and then you can use some integer maths and a pivot. If you can have values over 8,000 characters, I suggest looking for CLR functions. Or, better yet, don't pass delimited data in the first place and use a table type parameter.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: Have a look at this link too, may this helps you: https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/reaping-the-benefits-of-the-window-functions-in-t-sql-2

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky Sample data, table declaration, and desired output is there. The insert logic is what is missing and that I ask for: "Insert it into a temp table"
Did not think of SQL Server version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the following solution based on XML and XQuery.

It allows to get odd vs. even tokens in the input string.

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, descr varchar(max), meter int);

DECLARE @string varchar(max) = 'desc1$100$desc2$200';
DECLARE @separator CHAR(1) = '$';

DECLARE @xmldata XML = TRY_CAST('<root><r><![CDATA[' + 
      REPLACE(@string, @separator, ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + 
      ']]></r></root>' AS XML)

INSERT INTO  @tbl (descr, meter)
SELECT c.value('(./text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(30)') AS descr
    , c.value('(/root/*[sql:column("seq.pos")]/text())[1]', 'INT') AS meter
FROM @xmldata.nodes('/root/*[position() mod 2 = 1]') AS t(c)
   CROSS APPLY (SELECT t.c.value('let $n := . return count(/root/*[. << $n[1]]) + 2','INT') AS pos
         ) AS seq;

-- Test
SELECT * FROM  @tbl;
```

**Output**

```
+----+-------+-------+
| ID | descr | meter |
+----+-------+-------+
|  1 | desc1 |   100 |
|  2 | desc2 |   200 |
+----+-------+-------+
```

Comment: Not familiar with XQuery, but desired output is there.

Comment: @Thomas, it available in MS SQL Server since 2005.

Comment: Set as accepted answer, as this is actually inserting into the temp table as I asked.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example using JSON.

```
Declare @S varchar(max) = 'desc1$100$desc2$200'

Select Descr = max(case when ColNr=0 then Value end )
      ,Meter = max(case when ColNr=1 then Value end )
 From (
        Select RowNr  = [Key] / 2
              ,ColNr  = [Key] % 2
              ,Value
         From  OpenJSON( '["'+replace(string_escape(@S,'json'),'$','","')+'"]' )
      ) A
 Group By RowNr
```

**Results**

```
Descr   Meter
desc1   100
desc2   200
```

---

**If it helps with the visualization,** the subquery generates the following:

```
RowNr   ColNr   Value
0       0       desc1
0       1       100
1       0       desc2
1       1       200
```

Comment: This is pretty cool. Not seen this technique before. Must dig into this a bit and understand all of it.

Comment: This looks like a elegant solution. How is this in performance compared to the XML version below? 

Not that it will matter much for my case, since output probably will only reach 10 rows at max, but curious.

Comment: @Thomas When I run the two as a batch, the XML version has a relative cost of 100%.    So the XML version works, but is seems more expensive.

Comment: @Thomas Just to be clear, if your data is in a table, both can be run as  CROSS APPLY but the JSON approach would be easier (and I suspect more performant)

Comment: @JohnCappelletti The data is sent in as a parameter to a procedure. That is why I needed the insert into the temp table. And then use a cursor on that table again for other operations(Out of scope for this question).

Comment: @Thomas Seriously?  You couldn't add the INSERT INTO ... ?

Comment: @Thomas My intent was to DEMONSTRATE an elegant and performant technique. Developers deal in patterns and abstracts and need to show a little initiative.... we don't need to be spoon fed.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti The other answer answered the whole question with the INSERT into temp table, even though I'm using the JSON method you showed. Downvote as much as you like

Comment: @Thomas I literally never dispute OP's choice.  However, I have never witnessed a reversal for such a ridiculous and small reason.   Clearly the crux of the question was how to transform the string.   Now, If you were struggling with the INSERT, then perhaps you should hit the docs one more time.